# postion=fixed not working for moving news ticker

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The position=fixed works fine for some elements on my webpage but its not working for this news ticker that has to lie at bottom of page. Please help me to find the error. Thanks in advance !
This is my css code:-

```
.sticky_menu
    {
    position:fixed;
    //-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    //float:bottom;
    //height:200px;
    //width:1218px;
    //border:3px solid green;
    //box-shadow:0px -5px 5px #888888;
    }

                   #wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                margin: -100px 0 0 0;
                position: relative;
                left: 0;
                //top: 50%;
                font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #333;
                line-height: 22px;
                //min-height: 300px;
                //height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #wrapper h3 {
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #wrapper > div {
                background-color: #eee;
                border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 15px 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #wrapper > div.first {
                border-bottom: none;
            }

            #wrapper dl {
                display: block;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #wrapper dt, #wrapper dd {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 0 10px;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
            #wrapper dt {
                background-color: #f66;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #wrapper dd {
                color: #333;
                margin-right: 50px;
            }

            code {
                font-style: italic;
            }
```

This is my html code:-

```
<div class="sticky_menu">

<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="first">
                <dl id="ticker-1">
                    <dt>1.5.2014</dt>
                        <dd> APM Report updated</dd>

                    <dt>7.5.2014</dt>
                        <dd>EBAR(Account Level)report updated</dd>

                    <dt>9.6.2014</dt>
                        <dd>Digital Dashboard Pivot Table Report updated</dd>

                    <dt>10.6.2014</dt>
                        <dd>Safekey Report updated</dd>
                    <dt>13.5.2014</dt>
                        <dd>POINT Tool launched</dd>
                    <dt>1.6.2014</dt>
                        <dd>EBAR(Account Level) Report launched</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

This is the news ticker that I am referring to:-
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code at http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/9/

I think the main problem is your z-index, #c-footer has z-index: 10, so even if you give position:fixed and bottom:0; it will hide behind #c-footer div so you need to increase z-index of your News ticker(#wrapper) div

```
#wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: -100px 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Specify where you want the fixed element to be:

`.sticky_menu
    {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
.sticky_menu
    {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Should work